# How to avoid the return of system command with awk?

Tags: awk, system

When I use `awk` with `system command` like **this** :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ if ( system("wc -l file_1") == 0 ) {print "something"} }' text.txt >> file_1
```

the result of `system command` is writen in my file **file_1** :

```
0 file_1
something
```

How to **avoid** that? or just to **redirect** the output?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Are you simply trying to test for the existence of a file?

Comment: No, I test if the existing file is empty or not. "wc -l" -> 0

Comment: Then what about using `test -s file_1`, which creates no output but includes an exit value that will be used as `system()`'s return value? The `system()` function does not return the stdout of a command as its output. What you may be looking for is using `getline` with a pipe, but that's certainly not the best way to handle this. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29285396/1072112) for some other options.

Comment: To test is a file exists and is non-empty from awk would be `awk 'BEGIN{if ( (getline line < "file_1") > 0) print "something"}'` but we'd need to know more about what you're trying to do with the rest of your script to be able to tell if that was a reasonable thing to do or not.

Comment: @EdMorton - yes, that was in the answer I linked to, though the warning from Keith Thompson is important; `getline` terminates when it finds a newline, so if the file happens not to contain a newline, one can't limit how much memory `getline` will consume.

Comment: @ghoti True but then again a file without a newline isn't a text file per POSIX and no text-manipulation tool is required to work on a file that's not a text file anyway so if you're running an awk script on a file without newlines then you deserve what you get :-). For the OP, just FYI GNU awk sets a variable named ERRNO when getline fails so you can always look at that for specifc errors if you care.

Comment: To avoid output: replace `"wc -l file_1"` with `"wc -l file_1 >/dev/null"`.

Comment: `Cyrus` : it doesn't work in fact! because nothing append in my file.....:o(

Comment: Actually I'm in a large awk script and I need to check if a file in the same folder is already present and filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be under the impression that the output of the `system()` function includes the stdout of the command it runs.  It does not.

If you want to test only for the existence of a non-zero-sized file, you might do it using the `test` command (on POSIX systems):

```
awk '
  BEGIN{
    if ( system("test -s file_1") ) {     # a return value of 0 is "false" to awk
      print "something"
    }
  }' text.txt >> file_1
```

Comment: It works fine like this `system("test -s file_1")`  thank you!